# Overwrite shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation Method

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios6, autorotate

struggling with app im building. I'm using ECSlidingViewController, and it adds new views when they're opened by using:

```
[self.view addSubview:_topViewController.view];
```

Which is all and well, until i want to disable landscape on one view. My app launches on one view controller which i set autorotation to be disabled

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return NO;
}
```

How can i override this in another view controller, when its opened as a subview?

Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there is an easy way of making some screens portrait only and other both; Especially if one of your view is already in landscape mode and you want to open the next one portrait it is a pain. I am not sure about all your requirements. You should use supportedInterfaceOrientations together with shouldAutoRotate. If nothing works find out  the desired orientation and the current orientation and apply a transform to the view.

Comment: Well, in all but one view, I want the app to only run in portrait, so when the person rotates phone, it still stays portrait. But in one of my views, I want it to rotate to landscape too, as its a photo and want it make use of available space. Thanks.

Comment: I guess you can use CGAffinetransform and transform the view and apply the bounds of the view correct.

Comment: How would I do this, total newbie. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

view.transform =  CGAffineTransformRotate(view.transform, phaseShift * M_PI/2.0f);

U have to know what is the phaseShift to be used either 1 or -1 based on the device orientation and interface orientation.

Comment: Where would I put this, totally lost.